# Is it possible to force WebKit overflow scrolling even if scrolltop is 0

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I've been trying to force a scrollable div to still do its elastic effect even if scrolltop is 0 are at maximum. The ability to scroll the body or not appears to have nothing to do with it. If the element is at scroll position 0 it will not elastic.

I've tried to add 1px of padding on scroll end and then move scrolltop down a pixel but it's a poor solution.

WebKit overflow scrolling is a CSS property that allows a scrollable element on a webpage to mimic the native scrolling of the window on an iOS device. Provided the element needing to be scrolled is not at the top (scrolltop 0) and the user scrolls up the element will use full hardware acceleration and mimic how the window would elasticly scroll including the bounce effect at the end. Equally the element can be scrolled down mimicking full elastic scrolling unless IT is at the bottom at which point it scrolls the body instead. My question is if there is anyway to maintain the scrolling effect on the element as you would be able to do with a native app this scrolling the elemenht and not the body.

Comment: You question makes no sense. What is "webkit overflow scorlling?

Comment: Updated question explaining what WebKit overflow scrolling is

Comment: I'm not familiar with this webkit scroll. I've only used iScroll for that: 
[Demo](http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/simple/) &
[Download](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5)

Comment: If I understand right, you need overscroll on element even if content height doesn't cause scroll? If so, add absolutely positioned pseudo element with height more than 100% (top:0; bottom: -1). Try it out in inspector first.  It might work only after manual "bottom" change, in this case add 1s animation that changes bottom.